# setOnClickListener not working android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm learning android and kotlin, and I'm building a practice app. When I run my code the button isn't working and i don't know why or what I'm doing wrong/forgot to add. Any help is appreciated!

My xml code:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/solveBtn"
    android:layout_width="113dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="184dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Solve" 
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/NumInput" />
```

and my kt code:
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var num = NumInput.inputType.toInt()
    var answer = ansText

    fun solver (num1 : Int) {
        var div = 1
        var count = 0
        if ((num1 > 0) && (num1 < 2)){
            println("$num1 is a prime number!")
        } else{
            while (div < num1){
                if ((num1 % div) == 0){
                    div++
                    count++
                }else {
                    div++
                }
            }
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            answer.text = "$num1 is not a prime number"
        } else {
            answer.text = "$num1 is a prime number"
        }

    solveBtn.setOnClickListener{
        println("Hello")
        answer.clearComposingText()
        solver(num)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Again thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `solveBtn.setOnClickListener` is inside the `solver` function which is never called. Just put `setOnClickListener` call one curly brace lower.

Comment: Although now it seems that my output number is always 8194 no matter what number was entered so I don't know what's going on there.

Comment: That's because you're not reading the text, you're reading the `inputType` which is a constant. `var num = NumInput.inputType.toInt()`

Comment: How to I get the text and have it be a Int?

Comment: `Integer.valueOf(str)`. And you may want to ask additional questions in separate posts, not in the comments section.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up `setOnClickListener` outside `solver(..)`

```
fun solver (num1 : Int) {
    var div = 1
    var count = 0
    if ((num1 > 0) && (num1 < 2)){
        println("$num1 is a prime number!")
    } else{
        while (div < num1){
            if ((num1 % div) == 0){
                div++
                count++
            }else {
                div++
            }
        }
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        answer.text = "$num1 is not a prime number"
    } else {
        answer.text = "$num1 is a prime number"
    }
}

solveBtn.setOnClickListener{
    println("Hello")
    answer.clearComposingText()
    solver(num)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was so confused but I didn't catch that. I fixed the button but now I always get 8194 as the $num1 and I don't know why. If you happen to I would like to know, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Please use like this:

```
 backArrow.setOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

check the XML, sometimes when using `contraintLayout`, `android:enabled="false"` is set to `false` by default, set it to `true` or remove it